# Why does this conditional type fail to work with generic types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

I have the following generic type:

```
// Gets the keys of T where both the key and the value are strings.
export type StringValuedKeys<T> = {
  [P in string & keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? P : never;
}[string & keyof T];
```

It's used like this:

```
function myFunction<T, K extends StringValuedKeys<T>> { ... }
```

This work fine with concrete types:

```
type BaseType = {
  label: string
}

function testConditionalType() {
  // No error
  myFunction<BaseType, 'label'>()
}
```

However, it fails with generic types:

```
function testConditionalType<T extends { label: string }>() {
  // Error: `string` is not assignable to `StringValuedKeys<T>`
  myFunction<T, 'label'>()
}
```

Why does this fail in the second case? In the second example, `'label'` is still a string key of `T`, and `T['label']` is still a string. So shouldn't `StringValuedKeys<T>` include `'label'`?

Comment: TypeScript generally *defers* evaluation of conditional types that depend on generic type parameters.  Inside the body of `testConditionalType()` the compiler doesn't know what `T` is, so it doesn't bother trying to see what `StringValuedKeys<T>` is; it's left as this opaque type that nothing is obviously assignable to.  It doesn't "see" that `StringValuedKeys<T>` is a supertype of `"label"`; such higher order analysis isn't implemented.

Comment: See [ms/TS#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) and [ms/TS#47447](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47447) for related issues.  I could write this up as an answer if that addresses the question to your satisfaction.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, your solution from the first link worked for me: `function myFunction<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends StringValuedKeys<T>> { ... }`. If you write it up as an answer I'll accept :)

Comment: Okay I will try to write up an answer when I get a chance; I've been busy lately unfortunately

Comment: No rush--I actually found that it isn't quite sufficient for my use case, but I haven't had time to investigate further. As a workaround I'm repeating some code with different concrete types.